# Drush updates core successfully to 7.32 but is still 7.31

Tags: 7, drush, updating

I'm developing a site on Drupal 7 and using **drush 7.0-dev** to keep the core and modules up to date. I've run `drush pm-update` several times successfully in the past, until Drupal core version **7.32** came out. Everything seems to go fine and drush reports no errors, but the version still stays at **7.31** after the update.

Here's the output of two consecutive runs:

```
me@mybox:/var/www/customer$ drush pm-update
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message
 Drupal  7.31               7.32              SECURITY UPDATE available


Update information last refreshed: Thu, 10/23/2014 - 20:21
Code updates will be made to drupal core.
WARNING:  Updating core will discard any modifications made to Drupal core files, most noteworthy among these are .htaccess and robots.txt.  If you have made any modifications 
to these files, please back them up before updating so that you can re-create your modifications in the updated version of the file.
Note: Updating core can potentially break your site. It is NOT recommended to update production sites without prior testing.

Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Project drupal was updated successfully. Installed version is now 7.32.
Backups were saved into the directory /home/me/drush-backups/customer/20141023172524/drupal.                                                                                           [ok]
No database updates required                                                                                                                                                           [success]
'all' cache was cleared.                                                                                                                                                               [success]
Finished performing updates.                                                                                                                                                           [ok]
me@mybox:/var/www/customer$ drush pm-update
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message
 Drupal  7.31               7.32              SECURITY UPDATE available


Update information last refreshed: Thu, 10/23/2014 - 20:25
Code updates will be made to drupal core.
WARNING:  Updating core will discard any modifications made to Drupal core files, most noteworthy among these are .htaccess and robots.txt.  If you have made any modifications 
to these files, please back them up before updating so that you can re-create your modifications in the updated version of the file.
Note: Updating core can potentially break your site. It is NOT recommended to update production sites without prior testing.

Do you really want to continue? (y/n):
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why is the core not updating? Where should I start troubleshooting? I haven't tried a manual update yet, because I'd really rather get drush working again. The server is running Debian 7 and PHP 5.4.

Comment: One of my clients had the same issue. He run drush up again for the second time and it work. Would you like the steps do it manually ?

Comment: @darol100: I've tried running the update for about 10 times now. I've updated the core manually many times before I discovered drush, so that won't be a problem. :)

Comment: Maybe it's a cache issue? If you run `$data = unserialize(db_query("SELECT info FROM system WHERE name = 'system'")->fetchField());`, what's in `$data['version']`?

Comment: That's 7.31 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out - it was a permission problem. I hadn't noticed some of the directories drush was trying to update belonged to another user. Drush had no write permissions there but reported no errors. A quick `chown` later the update completed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `drush up drupal`. That may do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately the results were identical.

Comment: What's the output once the update completes?

Comment: The output is the same as in my question.

Comment: Try removing Drush and re-installing it. It sounds like a Drush issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar issue updating from 7.27 to 7.45 and I found that by changing my
/etc/apache2/site-available adn editing my 000-default.conf file
DocumentRoot /var/www

Mine were directing to the /var/www/html originally.
Drupal now recognises the updates which I did using Drush but I now have an AJAX HTTP error...
  Please excuse any ignorance as I am new to Drupal and IT. I hope this helps others who like me found changing permissions does not solve the issue.